# Where are the ILU and ILUT libraries after a successful build of DevIL for Ubuntu on ARM machine?

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-11.10, devil

I am trying to port an application that makes use of the DevIL library to open and save images. The application was developed under Ubuntu 10.04 on a PC, where `libdevil-dev` and `libdevil1c2` were installed automatically form the Software Center.

Now my new system is an ARM based embedded system running Ubuntu 11.10. Unfortunately I could not find DevIL in its Software Center. So I tried downloading the source code and build the package.

Following to the INSTALL file, I performed the following steps:

```
configure
make
make install
```

(with the `sudo` where required)

The build and install went fine, or so it seems. `make chack` also reported no errors.

Then, I tried building one on the examples supplied. Specifically, it was the OpenGL demo. But, when compiling the source file, using:

```
gcc -o gltest.e gltest.c -lIL -lILU -lILUT -lglut
```

I get the following linker error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lILU
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lILUT
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

looking at `/usr/local/lib`, I see `libIL.a  libIL.la  libIL.so  libIL.so.1  libIL.so.1.1.0` but no sign for `libILU` or `libILUT`.

How can I make the installer install the `ILU` and `ILUT` libraries, and respective header files, in place?

**UPDATE**:

running configure again, it concluded with the following message:

```
configure: +----------------------------------------+
configure: \| IL library  Supported formats \|
configure: +----------------------------------------+-------+
configure:  BLP BMP DCX DDS DICOM WAD FITS GIF HDR ICNS ICON IFF ILBM IWI LIF MDL MP3 PCX PCD PIC PIX PNM PSD PSP PXR RAW ROT SGI SUN TEXTURE TGA TPL UTX VTF WAL WBMP WDP XPM
configure: +----------------------------------------+
configure: \| IL library External libraries \|
configure: +----------------------------------------+-------+
configure: Required libs:  OpenEXR
configure: +----------------------------------------+
configure: \|      ILU part disabled       \|
configure: +----------------------------------------+-------+
configure: Pass --enable-ILU option to the configure script if you want to build ILU
configure: +----------------------------------------+
configure: \|      ILUT part disabled      \|
configure: +----------------------------------------+-------+
configure: Pass --enable-ILUT option to the configure script if you want to build ILUT
configure: +----------------------------------------+
configure: \| Detected Machine Extensions  \|
configure: +----------------------------------------+-------+
configure: 
configure: +----------------------------------------+
configure: \|  Not building any examples   \|
configure: +----------------------------------------+-------+
configure: Pass --with-examples option to the configure script if you want to build examples.
configure: +----------------------------------------+
```

So it seems like `ILU` and `ILUT` parts are not being built. Passing the suggested arguments now solved this problem.

Comment: If you check in the build folder, were those libraries built? Did the `configure` script find the OpenGL development files properly?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg - In the `lib/` directory I see many files named `libIL_la-il*`. In the `lib/.libs/` directory I see similar files, plus `libIL.so` and `libIL.a` and in `lib/.deps/` directory I see some `libILU_la-ilu*` and 'libILUT_la-ilut*` files.

Comment: Searching the filesystem, I cannot find any `*ILU*` files, except for the above mentioned, in the devil build directory.

Comment: I did not notice any complaint by `configure`.

Comment: When I run the `configure` script, at the end I get a message about `ILU` and `ILUT` parts being disabled, and that I have to add options to the `configure` script to enable them. Did you do that?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg - just posted an update with exactly that. I'll run it again.

Comment: Read the messages, it says _exactly_ what you have to do.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg - adding the command line options it seem to build and install the libraries now. I guess that is what happens when there is no explicit "error" or "warning" message in a long log dump, and when working in semi-batch mode. But then, the question probably deserves its -1 :-)

Comment: @JoachimPileborg - make it an answer an I can rep and accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To build the ILU and ILUT libraries, you need to add the arguments `--enable-ILU` and `--enable-ILUT` to the `configure` script:

```
$ ./configure --enable-ILU --enable-ILUT
```